# appending to remote file over SSH leads to line-by-line expansion

Tags: ssh, cat, certificates

I'm trying to append a certificate to a remote server's certificates file, using the folliwing command

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | minikube ssh 'sudo su - && cat >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
```

However, it seems that the remote host tries to evaluate the lines of text, rather than appending them to the remote file, leading to the following error mesages:

```
-sh: line 1: -----BEGIN: command not found
-sh: line 2:  MIIGETCCA/mgAwIBAgIQBNtwjkSfT+QGafgAnqb9JDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBK: No such file or directory
-sh: line 3: MQswCQYDVQQGEwJOTDEdMBsGA1UEChMUS29uaW5rbGlqa2UgS1BOIE4uVi4xHDAa: command not found
-sh: line 4: BgNVBAMTE0tQTiBOLlYuIFByaXZhdGUgQ0EwHhcNMTYwNzI4MDAwMDAwWhcNMTkw: command not found
-sh: line 5: NzI4MjM1OTU5WjCBhDELMAkGA1UEBhMCTkwxFTATBgNVBAgMDFp1aWQgSG9sbGFu: command not found
.
.
.
-sh: line 35: -----END: command not found
```

How can I prevent the lines from being evaluated and just have them added to the remote file?
Thanks!

Comment: I've no idea what `minikube` is but this is how I'd do it:  `openssl s_client -connect remote_server:443 </dev/null | sed -n '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | ssh user@hostname 'tee -a /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'`.

Comment: Thanks! "minikube ssh" is something like an alias for ssh user@minikube, in which minikube is the hostname. This approach with the standard ssh command keeps yielding the same errors unfortunately..

Comment: `sudo su -` starts a subshell that reads its input as shell commands. Why are you trying to use the certificate file as commands? It looks like it was intended to be the input to the `cat` command, but that doesn't run until after `sudo su -` finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're feeding the certificate as input to the `sudo su -` commands, so it's trying to execute it as shell commands. What you really want to do is run the `cat` command with `sudo`:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port |
    sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' |
    minikube ssh 'sudo bash -c "cat >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"'
```